Looking for name of a B-grade apocalyptic / (sort of) comedy movie set in a bunker where everyone is partying and dying of radiation poisoning
I am looking for the name of a B-grade nuclear apocalyptic movie mainly set in a bunker and everyone is partying. I watched it back in the early 90's so I think it's from the late 80's or 90's.
What I remember:

One of the party tricks (I think) is they stick their heads in a microwave oven to get a (buzz (?), I did say it's B-grade.)
There is one guy who agonises over asking a girl across the room for a dance.  By the time he gets the courage she is already dead from radiation poisoning and the guy goes nuts and drags her body around the floor and then he gets kicked out of the bunker.
At the end, two guys decide to leave the bunker and sit down among the city ruins and watch a incoming missile about to hit the city (I think the city is Melbourne.) One of the guys says "it's a mop-up strike" and they then get obliterated by the nuclear fire-ball.  That was the end.


Is this Smoke 'Em If You Got 'Em (1988)...?

When a nuclear war hits Melbourne, Australia, we find that there's more than one way to survive in the fallout - why sit around wasting what air's left when there's time now to get loose and dance?

It's a 48 minute-long black comedy that begins with Melbourne being obliterated by a nuclear strike. In the aftermath, three young male survivors find the entrance to an underground bomb shelter while biking through the ruins of the city and are invited in by one of the occupants.
When they get inside, they find dozens of people partying with the real-life band, Blue Ruin, playing live music. These people expect they'll all die soon from radiation-poisoning anyway, so as far as they're concerned, they might as well spend their last remaining hours getting drunk and high.
In an early scene, one of the newcomers partakes in a 'Bong and Bang Cocktail,' which involves him inhaling from a bong then getting his head defrosted in a microwave for about ten seconds. He's zonked out with a dopey grin on his face for quite a while afterwards.
In a later scene, another man is looking at a woman sitting across from him and trying to build up the courage to walk over and ask her to dance. By the time he finally does so, he finds that she died while he was procrastinating, and in his frustration, he hooks his arms under her armpits and tries to dance with her lifeless body.
Near the end, almost everyone in the shelter is lying on the floor dead or close to death. The last two guys still standing exit the shelter to spend what time they have left relaxing on a pair of sun loungers on the surface. Soon after, they spot a "mop-up strike" about to land in the distance and share a hug and some last words before the blast wave hits them.
You can currently watch the whole thing on YouTube. I won't link that video here, but here's a clip featuring the 'Bong and Bang Cocktail' scene.



